# How to get all data before seted date including hours in SQL

Tags: php, sql-server, symfony, date, datetime

Im coding some queries in PHP using DQL to get data of database depending the entities seted in the next form, the problem is when I compare 2 dates and the result is one day less than seted day, because the second date hour is fixed in 00:00:00 and the result is one day less than i putted in the form:

Form entities:

```
    User.php on line 7719:
array:5 [▼
  "dateFrom" => null
  "dateTo" => DateTime {#978 ▼
    +"date": "2017-11-21 00:00:00.000000"
    +"timezone_type": 3
    +"timezone": "UTC"
  }
  "name" => null
  "surname" => null
  "car" => null
]
```

Code example:

```
if ($form->get('button')->isClicked()) {

   $entity = $form->getData();

   $query = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:User')->createQueryBuilder('u');

   if ($entity['dateTo']) {

       $query->andWhere('u.requestDate<= :to')
                        ->setParameters(['to' => $entity['dateTo']]);
   }
   $resultQuery = $query->getQuery()->getResult();
```

Query result:

```
UserController.php on line 7772:
array:9 [▼
  0 => User {#3292 ▼
    -requestDate  => DateTime {#3289 ▼
      +"date": "2017-11-16 12:25:46.000000"
      +"timezone_type": 3
      +"timezone": "UTC"
    }
    -name: "Patrick"
    -surname: "Jhonson"
    -car: "Mercedes"
  }
  1 => User {#3296 ▼
    -requestDate  => DateTime {#3777 ▼
      +"date": "2017-11-17 13:30:15.000000"
      +"timezone_type": 3
      +"timezone": "UTC"
    }
    -name: "Peter"
    -surname: "Jhonson"
    -car: "Jaguar"
  }
  2 => User {#3299 ▼
    -requestDate  =>  DateTime {#3790 ▼
      +"date": "2017-11-21 06:51:29.000000"
      +"timezone_type": 3
      +"timezone": "UTC"
    }
    -name: "Anna"
    -surname: "Stark"
    -car: "Seat"
  }
```

The problem is that compare any date with date": "----/--/-- 00:00:00.000000"
When i set `dateTo` in form the date time that create to compare be a date with 00:00:00 hour, and I need compare this `data` with 23:59:59, because if hour of the day of `requestDate` > `dateTo` hours i get in `$resultQuery` all users before `dateTo` and not including `dateTo` day.

If y put get all users that `requestDate` => `2017-11-21` the result wil be `requestDate` > `2017-11-21` cause hour of the `dateTo` is 00:00:00

Comment: Why don't you compare dates only? e.g. `andWhere("DATE(u.requestDate)<= :to")->setParameters(['to' => $entity['dateTo']])` this is assuming `dateTo` is actually a date and not a datetime

Comment: okay i will try it

Comment: i have this error [Syntax Error] line 0, col 43: Error: Expected known function, got 'DATE'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume `$entity['dateTo']` is an instance of `DateTime` class, To get the result matching with your `dateTo` parameter irrespective of hour/time you can do a simple trick, just add one day to your parameter and change comparision criteria from `<=` to `<` so it will get you the expected output

```
$dateTo = $entity['dateTo'];
if ($dateTo) {
    $dateTo->add(new \DateInterval('P1D'));
    $query->andWhere('u.requestDate < :to')
          ->setParameters(['to' => $dateTo]);
}
```